# VB.Net / forms - Creating Folders with unique ID Numbers

Tags: vb.net, forms

I need to have a button that once clicked will create a folder in a pre-specified directory. The folder in question would contain a number with the year and 3 additional numbers in sequence. Formatted like this "2022001 Folder Name Generated From Text Box Here"
Once the user clicks the button again it adds +1 to the next folder ID "2022002 Folder Name Generated From Text Box Here"
The number would have to be stored so it could pick up where it left off after the program is closed.

What is the best way to go about doing this? Could you share a snippit?

Comment: As ALWAYS, think logic first and then write code to specifically implement that logic. It's too soon to post a programming question here because you haven't actually considered the logic.

Comment: Unless we're talking hug numbers of folders, the simplest option would to simply create the folder name in a `For` loop and then check whether that folder exists. Once you find a number that generates a folder name that doesn't exist, you create it. That's assuming that no folders get deleted. If you want to avoid recreating folders that were deleted then simply store the last value or next value in the application settings and use that directly.

Comment: We need to see some effort from you on your own behalf. It's not for us to simply write your code for you or teach you how to program. You need to make your best attempt and then ask us about a specific issue if and when you encounter it.

Comment: I just noticed that this question is flagged VB.NET and VB6. It can't be both. Don't trick people into viewing your question by applying irrelevant tags. ALWAYS read the tag descriptions and you would see that both explicitly state not to use them for the other.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Dim year = DateTime.Now.Year
Dim regex = New Regex($"{year:0000}(\d{{3}})")

Dim nextNumber = _
        Directory _
            .EnumerateDirectories("D:\Temporary") _
            .Select(Function(x) New DirectoryInfo(x)) _
            .Select(Function(x) regex.Match(x.Name)) _
            .Where(Function(x) x.Success) _
            .Select(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x.Groups(1).Value)) _
            .Max() + 1

Dim nextFolder = $"{year}{nextNumber:000}"
```

When I created these two folders `2022001` & `2022002 - Copy` and ran this code it produced:

```
2022003
```